# SAP .NET Connector 3.0 - ZQMTRANSP_DOREAD_FM "NO_PVP" internal error

Tags: c#, saprfc, sap-dotnet-connector

I have downloaded SAP .NET Connector 3.0 (https://github.com/ion-sapoval/NSAPConnector) and set up the connection parameters:

```
 <SAP.Middleware.Connector>
    <ClientSettings>
      <DestinationConfiguration>
        <destinations>
          <add NAME="DESTINY" USER="UZIVATEL" PASSWD="*****" CLIENT="001" LANG="EN" 
               ASHOST="192.168.132.197" SYSID="P" SYSNR="00" POOL_SIZE="5" 
               MAX_POOL_SIZE="10"/>
          ...
```

Afterwards, I have changed the lines with the "STRINGS" in the example code:

```
    using (var connection = new SapConnection("DESTINY"))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var session = new SapSession(connection);
        var command = new SapCommand("ZQMTRANSP_DOREAD_FM", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("PARAM1", "5");
        command.Parameters.Add("PARAM2", "000000900862");
        session.StartSession();
        var resultDataSet = command.ExecuteDataSet();
        session.EndSession();
        var sapDataReader = command.ExecuteReader("RESULTS");
   ...
```

When the code is executed it results with the internal error: **NO_PVP**

> ```
> NSAPConnector.CustomExceptions  {"An exception occurred when trying to execute corresponding 
> .NSAPConnectorException         function for the 'ZQMTRANSP_DOREAD_FM' on server.
>                                 Check inner exception for more details."} 
>   Data                          {System.Collections.ListDictionayInternal} 
>   HelpLink                      null
>   HResult                       -2146232832 
>   InnerException                {"NO_PVP"}
>     AbapMessageClass            ""
>     AbapMessageNumber           000
>     AbapMessageParameters       {string[4]} 
>     AbapMessageType             32 ' '
>     AbapT100Message             ""
>     Data                        {System.Collections.ListDictionayInternal} 
>     HelpLink                    null
>     HResult                     -2146232832 
>     InnerException              null
>     Key                         NO_PVP
>     Message                     NO_PVP
>     PlainText                   null 
>     Source                      sapnco 
>     StackTrace                    at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConnection.ThrowRfcErrorMsg() at SAP.Middleware.Connector.RfcConnection.RfcReceive(RfcFunction function) at SAP.M...
>     TargetSite                  {Void ThrowRfcErrorMsg()} 
>     Message                     An exception occurred when trying to execute corresponding
>                                 function for the 'ZQMTRANSP_DOREAD_FM' on server.
>                                 Check inner exception for more details.
>     Source                      NSAPConnector 
>   StackTrace                      at NSAPConnectorSapCommand.ExecuteRfc() in C:\Users\xxxxx\NSAPConnector-master\NSAPConnector.core\SapCommand.cs:line 194 at NSAP... 
>   TargetSite                    {SAP.Middleware.Connector.IRfcFunction ExecuteRfc()} 
>     Attributes                  Public | HideBySig 
>     CallingConvention           Standard | HasThis 
>     ContainsGenericParameters   false
> ```
>
> [image]

However, there is no error with different RFC function.
I guess the error is related to the fact that function ZQMTRANSP_DOREAD_FM contains a table.

Comment: ...and a new password for UZIVATEL please :-)

Comment: It looks like an error is thrown by the function module being called. Check with ST22 in the target system, please.

Comment: Will check it. Thanks.

Comment: This was an error within the RFC function. All it takes to fix that error was to set different language LANG="CS" within a destination. If only the error would be named for example UNSUPPORTED_LANG instead of NO_PVP.

Comment: @TomášKratochvíla As you have solved this issue but no answer was posted, I have added one which refers to your comment. Please complete if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As the issue was solved by the OP as per the comments, I'm just taking out these comments to highlight the solution and help others to see it more easily (NB: I'm not sure that the error can be seen in `ST22`, which would mean that there was a runtime error in the ABAP server, my opinion is that it's more an exception returned by `ZQMTRANSP_DOREAD_FM` and an ABAP debug of this FM is required to understand what produced it):

Jun 27, 2016 at 16:10

> *"It looks like an error is thrown by the function module being called. Check with ST22 in the target system, please."*

Original Poster of the question Jul 31, 2017 at 15:44

> *"This was an error within the RFC function. All it takes to fix that error was to set different language LANG="CS" within a destination. If only the error would be named for example UNSUPPORTED_LANG instead of NO_PVP."